# Make border of table-cell 100% of table width

Tags: html, css

I have the following markup:

```
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">1</div>
    <div class="cell">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">3</div>
    <div class="cell">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

With the following CSS:

```
.table {
  display: table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
}
```

The problem is that the border of the table-row only covers the width of its containing table-cells. I want the last table-row to have the same border width (horizontally of course ;)) like all the other table-rows, without changing its table-cell width or having to add another table-cell.

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tgry53ss/

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: You won't get the result you want if you are unwilling to change the width of the last cell or add another. Why not just use a `table` here? It seems like you are trying to render tabular data.

Comment: Firefox does it like you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no `rowspan` / `colspan` in CSS. You can use flexbox instead to achieve the results you wanted. It can also make the only cell to take the entire width available just like colspan does.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
.cell {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">1</div>
    <div class="cell">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">3</div>
    <div class="cell">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:** In case you don't wish the only cell to take the entire width, do this:

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
.cell {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Add this to your CSS:

```
.row:last-child::after {
  content:' ';
}
```

That way it will render another cell and its bottom-border without actually creating one.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6n4uozgh/)

Comment: Thanks! This actually works, but in my case, I prefer Pangloss answer, since it doesn't add an :after if it's not needed (if I actually have two cells in the last row). But thanks for your support!

Comment: The space is not necessary. Adding `display: table-cell` might be useful in order to be able to style the generated table-cell, otherwise it will be an anonymous parent element.

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming you set cell width to 50% because you had two cells in each row except last one, so one way of dealing with this will be using inline styling to override that width:

```
<div class="cell" style="width:100%">
    5
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I mentioned I don't want to change the with of the cell.